# How to get length of contiguous memory pointed at by char* after initializing it with malloc?

Tags: c, string, memory, char, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* buffer = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    memset(buffer,'\0',1000);

    printf("%ld\n",sizeof buffer);    // Size of Pointer
    printf("%ld\n",sizeof *buffer);   // Size of Memory Block pointed at by buffer
    printf("%ld\n",strlen(buffer));   // Length of String
    return 0;
}


//  Output:-
//  8
//  1
//  0
```

The code works fine.

The output is as expected, but how do I find the length of contiguous memory that I initialized with malloc if I don't know the length?

Comment: You have to give the memory size to malloc, so how can you be in situation where you don't know the size ?

Comment: I pass the pointer to a different function @Ôrel.

Comment: Yeah, that answers it @ kaylum.

Comment: I guess that was bad coding on my part, I should've allocated the memory in the function I used it in and passed it around for modification.

Answer (score 4):

There's no standard way to find out how large a block of malloc'ed memory is.

It's up to you to keep track of the size yourself.